# Laravel Passport/Oauth2 - Client authentication failed when generating authorization token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I have two laravel apps both have passport installed. Client running at port 8000 and server app running at port 9000.

On the client this is the code I use to initiate the oauth2 login procedure.

```
public function auth(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->put('state', $state = Str::random(40));

    $query = http_build_query([
        'client_id' => '2',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/authorize/response',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => '',
        'state' => $state
    ]);

    return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:9000/oauth/authorize?'.$query);
}
```

When I execute `auth` I get redirected to my server app there I do my login and then I get redirected to the redirect_url of the client. SO there this function is executed:

```
public function authResponse(Request $request)
{
    $state = $request->session()->pull('state');
    throw_unless(
        strlen($state) > 0 && $state === $request->state,
        InvalidArgumentException::class
    );

    $response = Http::asForm()->post('http://127.0.0.1:9000/oauth/token', [
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => '2',
        'client_secret' => '2DhRkOXmFHyNCY1k4mRhbRrR1TYP7pL77REruWT0',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/authorize/response',
        'code' => $request->code,
    ]);
    return $response->json();
}
```

This is my test environment so I don't worry to share client_secret:

[image]

So when `authResponse` is executed back on the client I get the following error:

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed","message":"Client authentication failed"}
```

The error here is shown on url such as:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/authorize/response?code=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&state=HZoSIbuBf3HEwN9qQdHF5YFvC3kBreD3zLsTjDEb
```

Do you have any idea what can be causing this issue and how can I fix it ? Why do I get this error?

Comment: My suspicion: The state set in :8000 won't be available to :9000, and thus that check fails.

Comment: @ceejayoz they are exactly the same sir I checked that.

Comment: You've got shared sessions between the two instances?

Comment: @ceejayoz no, it is not possible to have shared instances between two different aps.

Comment: @ceejayoz I don't think `:9000` cares about the `state` in any way here? The `authResponse` method is part of the "client" running under `:8000`. And the point of using a random state value in OAuth2 is for the client to be able to verify that it initiated the process (protection against CSRF-like attacks), the auth server itself isn't interested in that value at all.

Comment: @CBroe yes I agree. And there is no implementation for `state` checks or anything on the server side. Both functions that I have shown are on the client 8000 side. Any suggestion why it still gives this error ?

Comment: `invalid_client` suggests that either the client ID was wrong (which seems unlikely here), or that it didn't find a parameter by that name to begin with in the posted data. But I can't see any significant difference between your request, and the examples from the docs.

Comment: @CBroe exactly sir this is really anoying. I am trying even with postman to end up with same result. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Nothing besides debugging into it, and checking what is actually received at the endpoint.